# How to troublehoot VisualEditor (specifically 500 error)

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, visual-editor, parsoid, mediawiki-visualeditor

I am configuring VisualEditor for a mediawiki site. I've confirmed Parsoid is running on http://localhost:8000/ but I am still getting an error: Error loading data from server: apierror-visualeditor-docserver-http: HTTP 500. I'm not really sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: FWIW if you are not in too much of a hurry and can upgrade to MediaWiki 1.35 when it comes out late spring, that version will include a version of Parsoid that has been rewritten in PHP and integrated into the main wiki application, which makes setting it up much less of a hassle.

Comment: @Tgr This doesn't answer the question.